# How to make a model to distinguish positions using data from sensors?

Tags: model

**What I would like to do**

I need ideas about how to analyze data and make a model to distinguish positions where an object locates using data from receivers.

I don't know of a similar case like my problem, so I would appreciate sharing any of your ideas with me.

Comment: seems like a radar application not statistics

Comment: @Aksakal Which site should I ask this question for? What I would like to hear is statistical analysis of acquired data for distinguish positions.

Comment: you could train a neural net or SVM if you gather enough data

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If we imagine that like WIFI access points (APs) transmitters and receivers can do same job and they are able to transmit and receive signal then, we can resemble your scenario to **Localization Methods Based on Signal Lateration and Signal Strength Data Collection** then those relevant papers which they used **RSS-based localization techniques** to evaluate their model.
of course there are some problems on way of signal propagation due to:

- Effects of obstacles on signal travel(Reflection, diffraction, scattering)
- LOS(Lion-of-Sight)
- Multipath signals
- Signal degradation

considering your data type I think you can follow the approach in [Block-sparsity-based localization in wireless sensor networks](https://jwcn-eurasipjournals.springeropen.com/articles/10.1186/s13638-015-0410-6) by using **sparse approximation** and apply **RSS-fingerprinting** for creating a signature map (or dictionary) that represents the reference points.